# How do voyager convert to RTL version?

Tags: laravel-5.8, voyager, php-7.3

From `composer`

```sh
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "tcg/voyager": "^1.2"
}
```

I wanna convert voyager to `rtl` version, thanks.

Comment: Under config/voyager.php you have a option `'rtl' => false,` set it to true.

Comment: how to add custom RTL field in laravel voyager?

Answer (score 3):

1. add 'rtl'=>true to voyager file config in multilingual array.
2. change your local value to 'ar' or 'fa' or all rtl language in app.php config file.
3. clear config cache laravel with `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 1):

goto config/voyager.php in your laravel project

you will find an array which name is "multilingual", change 'rtl' option into true, it will rtl whole laravel voyager admin panel. code described below.

```
'multilingual' => [
    /*
     * Set whether or not the multilingual is supported by the BREAD input.
     */
    'enabled' => false,

    /*
     * Set whether or not the admin layout default is RTL.
     */
    'rtl' => true,

    /*
     * Select default language
     */
    'default' => 'en',

    /*
     * Select languages that are supported.
     */
    'locales' => [
        'en',
        //'pt',
    ],
],
```